# Unity3D custom Code Signing Identity for iOS

Tags: unity-game-engine

By default it seems that Unity 3D's XCode export uses the "iPhone Developer" Code Signing Identity. I need it to be "iPhone Distribution".

How can I tell Unity to use a different identity name?

Answer (score 0):

From my [old iOS notes](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/139684-FlightTest-this-device-has-not-been-given-permission-to-install-this-build), not sure if this is what you're talking about:

> At the top of the left panel, chose the left icon to show you folder structure. It will probably be minimised to only show "**Unity-iPhone**". Click on "**Unity-iPhone**". To the right of this it will say "PROJECT" with "**Unity-iPhone**" underneath. Click on this "**Unity-iPhone**". Chose the "**Build Settings**" tab to the right of this. Scroll down to the "**Code Signing**" section and set the Profile in the "Release" section.

Comment: What you seem to be describing is how to change the Code Signing Identity *in XCode*.  My question is how to specify the Identity *in Unity3D* so that it generates an xcodeproj with the right info.

Comment: @paleozogt You are correct, my apologies.  My notes didn't have any context.